# Octave 'wavread' undefined

Tags: octave, wav, audio-processing

I have GNU Octave 5.2.0, and I want to use it to analyze the IQ data in a wav file.  [This link](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Audio-Data-Processing.html) describes a function called wavread which I can use in Octave, but when I run `y = wavread(filename)`, I get this error message:

```
error: 'wavread' undefined near line 1 column 1
```

Why do I get this?  My best guess is that wavread is deprecated for some reason and only exists in earlier versions.  My other guess is that I have to install an extension to use wavread, but I didn't find a source that allows me to do this.

Comment: you can use [`audioread`](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Audio-File-Utilities.html#index-audioread)

Comment: Audioread doesn’t give me as much information as wavread would

Comment: @DanielCJacobs such as?

Comment: You are right about the deprecation, btw: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-5.1.html#deprecated-functions-and-properties

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou such as nbits.  I suppose I can either make audioread work or install an older version of Octave. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielCJacobs no need to reinstall just for `nbits`, you can use [`audioinfo`](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Audio-File-Utilities.html) to get that.

Comment: @DanielCJacobs also, have a look at octave forge what other "audio" related functions there are. That "mulaclab" at the bottom [of this list](https://octave.sourceforge.io/list_functions.php?q=audio&sort=package) may be of interest to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discovered by @TasosPapastylianou, the wavread function is [deprecated as of Octave version 5](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-5.1.html#deprecated-functions-and-properties).  Solution is to **use audioread function**.